# Transform rotateZ for text is blurry

Tags: css

I'm trying to get rotated text to be more crisp. I used `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`but it's still blurry. I was trying to follow the dabblet tutorial but couldn't get it right.

http://jsfiddle.net/2r3kqxp6/

http://dabblet.com/gist/2225318

Comment: You need to transform it on `hover`, check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2r3kqxp6/1/)

Comment: according to tutorial you have to transform rotate on hover

Comment: Hmm. Darn. Is there any other way to get sharper text without hovering?